# Read one double from base64 encoding in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, base64, limit

How can i read one value from a base64 encoded string?
if i have one array for example:

```
part = [1.2222,1.3333]
```

and i transform this array to binary representation, like this:

```
bin =  part.pack('G*')
```

and after that:

```
base64 = Base64.encode64 bin
```

the output its something like that:

```
base64 ="P/OOIZZSvTw/9VUyYXwb2g==\n"
```

So how can i read the first value in this format that ensures that i don't miss any character from the equivalent value?

The goal is to do after one limit and offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the exact reverse way: decode base64 string, unpack a value using the same format character (without `*` to get only one value)

```
base64 = "P/OOIZZSvTw/9VUyYXwb2g==\n"
base64.unpack('m')[0].unpack('G')[0]
# => 1.2222
```

or

```
Base64.decode64(base64).unpack('G')[0]
# => 1.2222
```

Comment: Thanks but i  can't unpack for know.. i only want to read a string to the equivalent value. and the problem is that i don't know how many characters represents one value, do you understand?

Comment: @user6776, Single `G` pack generate 8 bytes string. And base64 encode make 3/2-length of string. (ignoring the padding, issue for odd-length string)

Comment: @user6776, So you can use something like: `base64[0, 12].unpack('m')[0].unpack('G')[0]`

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, are you saying that the firsts 12 characters from the string represents a "float"?

Comment: @user6776, Yes, I am. Try `[[1.2222].pack('G')].pack('m').size` (You need to subtract 1 to exclude a newline character).  Or `[[1.2222].pack('G')].pack('m').chomp.size`

Comment: Nice when i encode the array of floats i do this: v = Base64.encode64(array_of_floats.pack('G*')).gsub(/\n/,'') so i don't need to subtract the newline

Comment: @user6776, Why don't yo use `String#chomp` as I did in the previous comment?

Comment: Because each "part" will be send to the server to append in the same file and i do the previous command. It's something wrong?

Comment: @user6776, I meant: Instead of `...gsub(/\n/, '')`, you can use `...chomp`.

Comment: (I'm a beginner :D )  Thanks a lot for your help !!